# How to navigate to a filesystem

Tags: filesystems, cd-command

I am using a cloud linux desktop and when I typed in `df -h` I get a list of filesystems as so:

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1            9.8G  4.5G  5.3G  47% /
tmpfs                  61G     0   61G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/xvdb             296G   27G  254G  10% /local
```

I want to go to `/dev/xvdb` since it has the largest diskspace. I tried to `cd` into it but that did not work. How do I get cd into it when I do not know where it is?

I tried to `cd /dev/xvdb` and this was the result:

```
cd /dev/xvdb
cd: not a directory: /dev/xvdb
```

Following the answer below this is what I have

```
(20-10-12 18:23:27) <0> [/local]  
dev-dsk % cd /dev/xvdb
cd: not a directory: /dev/xvdb
```

Comment: The `Mounted on` column tells you where it is: `/local`. So `cd /local`

Comment: How didn't it work?

Comment: @steeldriver I noticed that it could be in local but its a bit hard to find. Any idea on how to find the path?

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk When I try to cd into that filesystem it states that it does not exist.

Comment: Did you do `cd /dev/xvdb`? Post the entire command you used and output you got.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk Edited the question to reflect the entire command and output used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your command is incorrect - `/dev/xvdb` is not a directory on the
filesystem of the device, it's the device itself whose filesystem is `Mounted on` `/local` directory as shown in output of `df -h`. In other words, `/local` is a mountpoint for `/dev/xvdb` device. To
navigate to the filesystem stored on `/dev/xvdb` you need to go to its mountpoint:

```
cd /local
```

Comment: I made a comment following your answer. Still getting the same error.

Comment: As I said - `cd /dev/xvdb` is *wrong*, you have to do `cd /local` as explained.

Comment: I see, so I just need to cd into local?

Comment: Yes - you really need to do `cd /local`